# O que representam os ícones do navegador de objetos do Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Sabemos por este [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/y47ychfe(v=vs.100).aspx) o significado dos ícones principais, mas ainda existem alguns que não estão claros, e aparecem no **Visual Studio**, como por exemplo: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] ou [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Existe outra tabela conhecida com esta legenda e contendo todos os ícones?

Comment: A explicação do cadeado está no próprio link que você forneceu.

Answer (score 1):

Os links abaixo apontam pra páginas (en) com os ícones para as suas respectivas versões do Visual Studio:

- [VS 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe(v=vs.120).aspx)
- [VS 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [VS 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [VS 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166402%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
- [VS 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166402(v=vs.80).aspx)

Até VS 2008 eram chamados de *babel icons*, mas essa nomenclatura parece que deixou de ser usada nas versões mais novas (agora são somente *object browser icons*).